To what extent are people's preferences quasilinear?
In many economic models (e.g. in auction theory, as well as fair division), it is common to assume that the agents' preferences are quasilinear, that is, their utility to a bundle of items and money is their value for the items plus the money.
It is easy to think of settings in which this assumption is not accurate, for example, for people that are very rich or very poor, the utility is usually not linear in the money. My question: are there empirical studies that check how "close" are usual people's preferences to being quasilinear -- how far they are from the quasilinear model?
I found several papers on empirical examinations of utility functions on lotteries, e.g. here; I am not interested in utilities on lotteries, but on utilities on deterministic bundles that contain a combination of items and money.

I'm not sure if this is a well-defined question. Money is not good; its value comes from buying stuff. So, the usual interpretation is that a utility function of the form $u(x,m)=v(x)+m$ has $m$ representing the indirect utility of other goods under fixed prices. Whether this is a good representation or not depends on which good you choose to be the $x$ here.
